# Получение значения XML тега

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Ни как не могу спарсить текст <version> между </version>:

```
    var rgx = new Regex("<version>([0-9]+)<\version>");
    var artmatch = rgx.Match(html);
    string version = artmatch.Groups[1].Value;
    MessageBox.Show(version);
```

Comment: дык, там слеш в другую сторону

Comment: Поменял. Всё равно реакция 0.

Comment: WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://bot.mobileprison.ru/information/Inferno");
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var rgx = new Regex("<version>([0-9]+)</version>");
        var artmatch = rgx.Match(html);
        string version = artmatch.Groups[1].Value;
        MessageBox.Show(version);

Comment: <version>1.0</version>

`1.0` не совпадёт с шаблоном `[0-9]+` - попробуйте .+


а вообще, если там какое-то подобие xml, то возможно имеет смысл достроить его до валидного xml (добавить объявление и корневой элемент) и скормить родному xml парсеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуй

```
var rgx = new Regex("(?<=<version>)(.*)(?=</version>)");
var artmatch = rgx.Match(html);
string version = artmatch.Groups[0].Value; //Groups[0], а не Groups[1]
MessageBox.Show(version);
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы парсите XML, логичнее было бы использовать [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/System.Xml(v=vs.110).aspx), а не регулярки

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"путь_к_файлу.xml");
XmlNode versionNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//version"); //xpath до тега version
string value = versionNode.InnerText;
```